# Configurator with image updates

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm looking for the best way to develop a configurator for products.
The configurator works in this way, user chooses model, color, optional and at the same time that they choose the main image is updating.

I think that I have two way to do this:
1. an image for each combination and via JS I update the URL of main image
2. an image (PNG transparent) for each part that change and merge all image with PHP

What you think? which solution is the best? Have you any suggestion?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research? As it is, this question is too broad, and will probably be closed as such. Try to search around a bit for possible solutions, try coding something, and come back for help (With a example of what you tried), if you can't get it to work. SO is not a site where you can just post a requirement and expect code in return.

Comment: I researched around but I didn't find nothing that could help me to choose the best way, I don't want code I need only suggestion from who just did it or something similar.

Comment: Well the “an image for each combination” approach might need _a lot_ of images (depending on the number of options and possible choices).

Answer (score 1):

I think that from what you have said the question is not really about code, it is more what is the best way for you to display a product and that product in various different configurations. You are correct that the code itself should offer the means to select the options, and that java-script can be used to take those options 'on the fly' and display the resulting image.

Whether you use as many images as combinations for options, or a number of images that can be overlay-ed to create many different combination depends on how many combinations you have, and how much time it would take to take all the those photos. From a code point of view, it makes no real difference.

The simplest solution is just to show an image with a url. If you use one image just make each combination append a code to the url as follows

**Make**

Audi = audi

Bmw = bmw

**Color**

White = WW

Red = RR

**Doors**

2 = 02

4 = 02

**Alloy Wheels**

yes = 01

no  = 00

A bmw in white with 2 doors and alloys would be image:

bmw-ww0201.png

Depending on what controls you use for selecting options, you would just need to circle your form an place all the option values into an array. Join the array to form the string and you have a nice neat url

I have not shown any code. If you give us a sample product form. I'm sure we can make it work.

On the other hand you could place all the images for options on the page, make them all 'hidden' and use java-script again on the fly to un-hide options as they are selected on the form. The images could be all overlayed positioned correctly using css. By adding them all to the page, they will pre-load making a faster UI.

Comment: The solution I would choose would be based purely on number of combination of images and complexity of photography not on the code.